# SpannableStringBuilder not working in TextView Android

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I am stuck while setting the text color of a word in `TextView`.

Below is my code :

```
     final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(first + next);

    // Span to set text color to some RGB value
final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(0,0,255));

    // Span to make text bold
 final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);

    // Set the text color for first 4 characters
sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, first.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

    // make them also bold
 sb.setSpan(bss, 0, first.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
  textView.setText(sb);
```

Here is the XML of TextView -

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/description_text" />
```

My Tries -

1. Set this but no results.

   android:textAllCaps="false"

Comment: I tried your code and it works. What result you are getting?

Comment: @maxost I am trying this in Fragment and Recycler View. Please let me know, if i need to do something extra.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @maxost This is not changing the color of a  word :(

Comment: Please show where are you calling your code

Comment: I am calling my code inside  onBindViewHolder method

Comment: Remove `android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"` from XML and check is text still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131001/discussion-between-shoeb-siddique-and-maxost).

Comment: Did you find any workaround ? I'm having the exact same problem